# android saving state of many layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a simple chat app where a RelativeLayout with multiple views is created for each message. After the activity is stopped or destroyed all of my added layouts disappear from the parent so all messages are gone.

Sure I could put the ID (along with other values) of each single view into a SharedPreferences object or a database to restore all messages after the activity is re-created.. but is there a simpler way to save the dynamically created layouts..? The parent is defined by XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an `Activity` (or a `Fragment`) becomes invisible - its `View` hierarchy gets destroyed, and you can't overcome that. In fact, you don't need too. The solution is to store the messages inside a database and recreate the `View` hierarchy on `Activity` startup based on the database contents. No need to reinvent the wheel here. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Collection of messages in the Bundle savedInstanceState at OnSaveInstanceState() and restore them in your onCreate() from that.

Comment: I can't put view objects in the Bundle, so this also means that I have to save all the values and re-create views from this values

Comment: You're not supposed to save view objects. The views will be re-created but you save the app from fetching/generating the data to show again.